# C++ console http api app deployed on Windows Server 2012 is not accessible externally

Tags: c++, windows-server-2012

I am trying to deploy a simple `HTTP API` app on an `Window Server 2012` and it's not working. **The app is accessible internally (I can ping it within the server) but NOT externally**. What do I need to do make the API server accessible via network? I disabled the firewall so it's not a firewall issue. I would usually use Linux, but I don't have a choice but use Windows this case. Please help!

Comment: How do you ping a HTTP API? Do you perhaps mean you can locally send a HTTP request to it and get a reply? Do you want to access it from another machine on the local network or from an external IP address?

Comment: Yes, I send a HTTP request locally and get a response. And yes, what I want is to be able to access it from an external IP. I actually solved it by installing IIS and use it as a proxy server... though this is pretty dumb to use IIS just so that my web app is accessible externally. My web app should be just accessible directly

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing IIS and use it as a reverse proxy. So when a http request comes in from the internet, IIS it takes it and forwards it to my web app.. I am not sure this is the right way or not, but if it is, then it's pretty stupid as my web app should be accessible directly which would have been the case if I were using Linux.

Comment: How does IIS forward it? Since IIS is already listening on port 80, your web app is not. What is the local address/URL and port that IIS forwards it to?